# How to I use jQuery to identify selectors that I need?

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have code that looks like this:

```
<div class="tag">Order # :</div>
<div class="data">
<input type="text" name="oemTeo[<?=$o;?>]" id="o_oemTeo[<?=$o;?>]"  value="<?=$vrow['oemTeo'];?>" />
</div>
```

I want to select (and apply some css to) the `<div class="tag">` element directly BEFORE the `<div class="data">` element. How would I define that selector using jQuery. I've tried `$(this).prev('div .tag')` but it did not work.

Thanks

Comment: `this` is actually the `input` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments, since `this` refers to your `<input>` element, you need to go to the [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) `<div>` before going to the previous sibling with [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/), like this:

```
$(this).parent().prev("div.tag");
```

[`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) works only on **sibling** elements, and the `<div>` you're after isn't a sibling, but rather a sibling of the parent...so you just need to traverse up to that first.

Answer (score 1):

If `this` is the `div.data` element, just remove the space from your selector (or eliminate the selector altogether):

```
$(this).prev('div.tag');
```

---

...or if you need to select from the DOM, you could do this:

```
$('div.tag + div.data').prev();
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

$('div.data').prev().css('background-color', 'red');

this goes back to figuring out what 'this' is like nick said.

Answer (score 0):

Since 'div' with class 'tag' is a sibling for 'div' with class 'data', you can use 'siblings()' method as :

```
$(function(){

    var previousElement = $('div.data').siblings('div.tag');

    console.log(previousElement);

});​
```

fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/jAnS8/1/